# rank of matrix from it's adjoint rank

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and let rank of it's adjoint be 1. Does it necessarily imply $rank$  $A = n-1$?

I know the reverse implication is true, but I am unable to find a proof/counter example for this one. All I know is that there is only one linearly independent $(n-1)*(n-1)$ minor. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the rank of $\text{adj}A$ is $1$.

If the rank of $A$ is less than $n-1$ then every $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minor is $0$, and so the rank of $\text{adj}A$ is $0$.

If the rank of $A$ is $n$ then $A$ is nonsingular, and as $A\  \text{adj}A=(\det A) I$ we have that $\text{adj}A$ is also non-singular. Since the rank of $\text{adj} A$ is $1$ this forces $n=1$.

Hence the rank of $A$ is $n-1$ **provided $n>1$**.

Comment: That was quite simple and elegant. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume $n\ge2$. If $A$ has rank $n$, it and its adjoint are invertible,
and the adjoint has rank $n$.

If $A$ has rank $\le n-2$, its adjoint is zero, since every $(n-1)\times(n-1)$
submatrix of $A$ is singular.

Th interesting case is when $A$ has rank $n-1$. Then $A$ has a non-singular
$(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix so $\text{adj}\, A\ne0$. But $(\text{adj}\, A)A=0$
so the columns of $A$ are in the null space of $A$ which is one-dimensional.
The adjoint has rank $1$.

If the adjoint has rank $1$ then $A$ must have rank $n-1$.